# Empty Print Queue Using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba7

I am using MS Access 2019

I want to empty the print queue (Using VBA) for a specific printer...if this cannot be done just empty all print jobs on all printers.

I am creating a POS using Access 2019.  At one point the program ask if customer wants a receipt.  IF the answer is NO I want to empty the receipt from the queue.  What is happening now is I will get 100 customers who say NO, the 101th says yes and the entire print queue prints 101 receipts (all the past "NO")

The Computer: Windows 10 and 11

Printer: STAR TSP700II receipt printer (printer designated on receipt report)

I have tried this code but get an error:

Dim qd As Object
Set qd = CreateObject("Shell.Application").NameSpace(16)
qd.ParseName("EPSON WF-2650 Series").InvokeVerb ("Empty")

ERROR: Object variable or With block variable not set

Actual printer name from printer properties:  "EPSON WF-2650 Series" which is 21 characters
I call this code from a msgbox answer..........Call EmptyPrintQueue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code cancels all print jobs from all printers:

```
Public Sub OhSht()
    Dim o As Object, ret
    For Each o In GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}//./root/cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_Printer")
        ret = o.CancelAllJobs
        Debug.Print o.Name, ret
    Next
End Sub
```